# Stack Overflow actions extremely slow

Tags: bug, performance

Today Stack Overflow seems plagued by slowness.  Editing answers and even clicking links from Hot Network Questions is taking a long time (> 20 seconds).  Looking at the network log, it seems it is coming from some tracking endpoints:

```
stackoverflow.com/gps/event
stackoverflow.com/posts/validate-body
```

Both of those are loading very slowly.  Other Stack Exchange sites are not seeing the same issue.

I am running Chrome 58.0.3029.81 on Windows behind a company firewall.

Comment: Sorry, it's just you:(

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I put both of those files in my ad blocker and everything is great now.  Odd.

Comment: Power-cycle all your routers:)

Comment: I did experience some unusual slowness yesterday. It seemed to take a long time for some scorecard stuff to load. I'm not seeing it today though.

Comment: Company routers.  No control.  Oh well.  I have a workaround.